# Context is read only error in grails app

Tags: java, grails

I'm trying to use de GROBID JAVA API using the example in http://grobid.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Grobid-java-library/ in grails app. 
The following code in JAVA (Netbeans) works well:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    String pdfPath = "/home/jose/plantilla_Informatica_2015 (ok).pdf";
    String pathGHome = "/home/jose/GROBID_COMPILED/grobid-home";
    String pathGProp = "/home/jose/GROBID_COMPILED/grobid-home/config/grobid.properties";

    try {
        MockContext.setInitialContext(pathGHome, pathGProp);
        GrobidProperties.getInstance();

        Engine engine = GrobidFactory.getInstance().createEngine();
        BiblioItem bi = new BiblioItem();

        String doc = engine.processHeader(pdfPath, false, bi);
        System.out.println(doc);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(GROBID.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    finally{
        try{
            MockContext.destroyInitialContext();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            Logger.getLogger(GROBID.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

When I copy to grails the same code with the same set dependencies, 
and put the grobid-core.jar inside the folder lib  it gives me the error:

```
| Error 2016-03-11 16:50:22,195 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR    errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - OperationNotSupportedException occurred when processing request: [GET] /GROB/grobid
Context is read only. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Context is read only
    Line | Method
->>  961 | checkWritable     in org.apache.naming.NamingContext
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    548 | createSubcontext  in     ''
|    574 | createSubcontext  in     ''
|    487 | createSubcontext  in org.apache.naming.SelectorContext
|    483 | createSubcontext  in javax.naming.InitialContext
|     37 | setInitialContext in org.grobid.core.mock.MockContext
|     76 | setInitialContext in     ''
|     17 | index             in grob.GrobidController
|    198 | doFilter . . . .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter          in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run               in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . . . . . in java.lang.Thread

Process finished with exit code 137
```

My Grobid controller:

```
import org.grobid.core.data.BiblioItem
import org.grobid.core.engines.Engine
import org.grobid.core.factory.GrobidFactory
import org.grobid.core.mock.MockContext
import org.grobid.core.utilities.GrobidProperties

class GrobidController {

    def index() {

    String pdfPath = "/home/jose/plantilla_Informatica_2015 (ok).pdf"
    String pathGHome = "/home/jose/GROBID_COMPILED/grobid-home"
    String pathGProp = "/home/jose/GROBID_COMPILED/grobid-home/config/grobid.properties"

        MockContext.setInitialContext(pathGHome, pathGProp)
        GrobidProperties.getInstance()

        Engine engine = GrobidFactory.getInstance().createEngine()
        BiblioItem bi = new BiblioItem()

        String doc = engine.processHeader(pdfPath, false, bi)
        println(doc)

        MockContext.destroyInitialContext()

    }

}
```

My BuildConfig dependencies:

```
 dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        // runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        test "org.grails:grails-datastore-test-support:1.0-grails-2.4"

        compile "directory-naming:naming-java:0.8"
        compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.7"
        compile "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1"
        compile "com.cybozu.labs:langdetect:1.1-20120112"
        compile "com.google.collections:google-collections:1.0"
        compile "net.arnx:jsonic:1.3.5"
        compile "fr.limsi.wapiti:wapiti:1.5.0"
        compile "commons-io:commons-io:2.0.1"
        compile "com.google.guava:guava:16.0.1"
        compile "xom:xom:1.2.5"
        compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.7"
        compile "log4j:log4j:1.2.17"
    }
```

**### EDIT #####**

if I build a war of the same application and run it with

```
grails run-war target/GROB-0.1.war
```

It works well !!!!

What can be happening?
Any help ?
Thanks in advnace.

Comment: As a first step, have you added grobid as a dependency? `compile 'org.grobid:grobid-core:0.3.4'`

Comment: That exception is coming from Tomcat. You can see it here: https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/86b1281a190ec2f17fd1ac5ae3d3889166dcd360/java/org/apache/naming/NamingContext.java#L963 Were you using Tomcat when the code was working?

Comment: I copied the latest version of grobid in the lib folder (called grobid-core-0.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar), by adding compile "org.grobid:grobid-core:0.4.0" in BuildConfig.groovy, the console print: Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.grobid:grobid-core:jar:0.4.0 (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa yes, I am using tomcat, How i can fix this error ? Thanks for your time !